# PHP and Java encoding issues

Tags: java, php, web-services, encoding

I recently wrote a webservice that runs as a Java application (probably not the best idea, but I'm more fluent in Java than in other languages like PHP or English :p). The Java application simply outputs the JSON data to System.out.

And then I wrote a tiny PHP script that uses the Java application.

Here is my PHP script :

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
passthru("java -jar webservice.jar ");
```

The issue is that every special char (like "é") is output as "??"

Any idea of what I could try to fix that encoding issue ?

Thanks

EDIT : when I run `java -jar webservice.jar` in a shell, I have no encoding issue

Comment: Is this in the browser or on the command line?

Comment: In a shell command line I have no encoding issue (edited post to add this fact). In browser (or in my mobile client app) the issue appears, that's why I believe it's related to the php script

Comment: @Estragon Are you sure the output is actually UTF-8 encoded? What happens when you change the encoding to Latin in your browser?

Comment: No change when setting another charset :(

Comment: The PHP manual states, that passthru should be used mainly for binary data output. Try using system() maybe?

Comment: I just changed from passthru to system. No change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`to my java call :

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar webservice.jar
```

I guess there may be a better solution but it solved my problem so :)

Answer (score 1):

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Sounds like you need to make sure you are handling the double byte characters correctly :)

More on encoding: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is a problem that covers a lot of variables: operational system, app, bd etc.

Try to follow this: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8